# Forge model derivative job failed. What now?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I ran a model derivative job and the status came back: failed. After drilling through the return values, it said that two of the linked dwg files were missing. I added the dwg files, re-zipped and re-uploaded the zip. When I try to run the job, it keeps coming back with the initial failed status. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have **buckets**, on the [POST Job](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) endpoint, use the `x-ads-force` header, if you pass `true` it will translate again the file.

Answer (score 0):

In hindsight, one could say this is obvious but it isn't spelled out in any documentation anywhere. Essentially, one needs to DELETE the failed manifest and run a new job. There doesn't seem to be any re-try mechanics.