# Model Derivative API - Conversion from dwg to obj

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I have been trying to convert a dwg file into an obj file using the model derivative API following the viewer tutorial. It works fine with the input files and output formats provided in the tutorial; however, when using a dwg file as input and changing the output to obj, I get the following

> error: Error at Model Derivative job.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Can the model derivative API convert dwg to obj?

Looking at the console, I can see the following line in the response: '**x-ads-troubleshooting**': 'The system does not support this file format.',

Comment: Please see attached link for the same [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109009/12489279](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109009/12489279)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate DWG to OBJ is not a supported translation.